# Mongoose route isn't getting query data from axios function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

Data being sent to the axios function isn't getting to the mongoose route in the back-end. The data is getting to the axios function from the front-end in react, but isn't making it to the back-end.

Front-end calling Axios

```
    const bugQuery = {
      GroupID: "FRITOS",
    };

    this.props.getBugs(bugQuery);
```

Axios function

```
export const getBugs = (item) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log(item);
  axios.get("/api/bugs", item).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_BUGS,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};
```

Mongoose route

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  Bugs.find({ GroupID: req.body.GroupID }).then((items) => res.json(items));

  console.log("Bugs loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `req.body` in a GET method it's available just in POST, PUT and PATCH methods

update:
or just use request params like this

```
export const getBugs = (item) => (dispatch) =>         { 
    console.log(item); 
    axios.get(`/api/bugs/${item.groupId}`).then((res) =>           

        dispatch({ type: GET_BUGS, payload:   res.data, }) ); 
};
```

backend:

```
router.get("/api/bugs/:id", (req, res) => { 
   console.log(req.params.id);    
   Bugs.find({ GroupID: req.params.id }).then((items) => res.json(items)); console.log("Bugs loaded"); 
});
```

Comment: then how would I access the data in the method?

Comment: I just updated my answer on how to use req params, hope it saves you